# Is there a way to execute system commands from within nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am looking to start some service using the command line tool from within the nightwatch. Searched a lot over the internet but found nothing related.

Appreciate if someone can provide an example to execute system commands.

Comment: can you add a bit more information on what you are trying to achieve. Also please share the code that you tried.

Comment: I would like to run system commands. Tried below code:

`
test('start minikube', client => {
    const cmd = "ls -lrt"

    client.execute(function (){
      const execSync = require('child_process').execSync
      execSync(cmd)
    }, [])
  })
`

Getting below error:
Error while running .executeScript() protocol action: An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript. – javascript error: execSync is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code using NodeJS code and definitely not NightwatchJS. I have noticed that you are trying to execute it using `client.excute()`. Please note that this runs in the browser and not in the system. You should explicitly run your system code using NodeJS and outside Nightwatchjs commands.